# Will a FCM message, open a firebase database connection?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to know, if my app is in background and it recieves a fcm message, will this automatically open a firebase connection to sync my active references? 
I would like to run a service on recieving a fcm message which then attaches a onChildAdded and singleValueEvent listener to a database ref (keep_synced true) and performs the actions in background, and then the service stops itself when the value event occurs. Wanted to know if this approach guarantees that I will receive all the children added to that location by that time ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This topic (push-to-sync) is quite broad. I wrote a small answer below, mostly to give you some links to get started with.  But unless you make your question more concrete and show code of where you're stuck/have a concern, I will vote to close it (although it's certainly interesting).

Answer (score 1):

NO. You have to update the value by yourself. FCM is a replacement of GCM, it is used just to send notification.
You can handle the FCM and then call the listener which update all the child at that node.

Comment: My server adds a child in that ref and then also sends a fcm message to the user, now when in foreground i can use the listener to get the child but when my app is in background, i need to rely on fcm. So my question is if I just send an empty fcm message to the user (which i guess removes the network restrictions for some time), so when the message is received, will the ref (keep_synced true) be also synced automatically so that i don't have to process the fcm message but just use a listener to get the child ?

Comment: See, you have to sync all the children when receive a notification, just like you would do when a user starts your activity.
If you show notification when you receive a FCM, you can also sync your database there.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have much reputation to upvote you tho :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there will be no automatic connection to the Firebase Database when the FCM message is received.

You'll have to [process the FCM message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#override-onmessagereceived) for that and then [reconnect your database listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) or [go online](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabase#-goonline).